# Metric Space - Open Balls

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

The question is: Find $B(2,3)$ in $(\Bbb{R},\rho)$ where $\rho$ is the metric given by $\rho(x,y) = \min\{1, |x-y|\}$.

Request: check if my logic as under is correct:-

$B(2,3) = \{y \in \Bbb{R} \mid d(2,y)<3\}$

$d(2,y) = \min\{1,|2-y|\}$

That is  $\min\{1,|2-y|\} < 3$

If $2-y>0$, then $\min\{1,2-y\} < 3$, i.e., $y>-1$

if $2-y<0$, then $\min\{1,y-2\} <3$, i.e., $y<5$

Hence required ball is $(-1,5)$

Comment: Do your own homework

Comment: What do you mean by B(2,3)

Comment: @hunch He says what that means in point 3.

Answer (score 2):

You're good up to step 5. Recall that the smallest element in a set can never be larger than any element in that set. This implies that for any $a \in \mathbb R$, we have that:
$$
\min\{1, a\} \leq 1 < 3
$$
Hence, the predicate of the set in step 3 is a tautology. So $B(2, 3) = \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of $\rho(x,y)$. It implies that for every real number pairs, like $x$ and $y$, $\rho(x,y)$ is always lower than\equal to one. This means, the ball $B(2,3)$ contains every element of $\Bbb{R}$, because for every element $a$ in $\Bbb{R}$, you have $d(2,a)\leq1<3$.